# Objective C - Restore an external running application from minimize to normal

Tags: objective-c, macos, restore, minimize

So I have code like this:

```
- (void)sendAnswerXlite:(NSDictionary*)softPhone
{
__block NSString * identifier = [softPhone objectForKey:kSoftPhoneAppIdentifier];
NSAssert(identifier != nil, @"Nil identifier argument in answer input");
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_menu_hotkey_queue(), ^{
    // check if app is running
    NSArray * apps = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:identifier];

    if (apps != nil && [apps count] > 0)
    {
        NSRunningApplication * frontmostApp = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] frontmostApplication];
        NSRunningApplication * runningApp = [apps objectAtIndex:0];
        if ( !([runningApp isEqualTo:frontmostApp]) )
        {
            [runningApp activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateAllWindows];
            //[runningApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
        }
    }
}
```

But even if I use activateWithOptions or activateIgnoringOtherApps, it will only set focus to the external application, but if application was already minimized then it will not show the window X-Lite but the menu bar will show (in this case)X-Lite. The identifier is just the bundle identifier of the application.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, were you able to find a solution?